# How to display the response json variable in laravel blade?

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to display return response json in view blade of laravel.
But it's can not be work:-
IN my controller:-

```
  return response()->json(['status_message' => $this->status_message, 'alert_type' => $this->alert_type]);
```

I just want to display the assign value of status_message and alert_type in view blade but it's can not be work.
Please help me to solve out this issue.
I feel glad for it.

Comment: What do you mean with "not work"?

Comment: could you add your view code too?

Comment: Not I am confused how to write code to display of jso response message in blade view.

Comment: Add `{{ $status_message }} {{ $alert_type }}` to your view file.

Comment: did you mean you want to display json alone in your view?  or you want just to display it somewhere in your inputs inside your view

Answer (score -1):

Since you are returning the json data with `status_message` and `alert_type`, we have the two variable with us but here Laravel doesn't know where the response needs to be shown.

If you are returning the api call than it is okey, you just need to manipulate the `status_message`  and `alert_type`, but if it is for the view you need to return the view where you want to use the variable.

i.e.

```
return view('index', ['status_message' => $this->status_message, 'alert_type' => $this->alert_type]);
```

this returns the index.blade.php with two variables as `$status_message` and `$alert_type`.

My **index.blade.php** is located at this directory structure:

```
|-resources
   |- assets
       |- views
            |-index.blade.php
```

You could use it like:

**index.blade.php**

```
<span> {{ $status_message }} </span>
<span> {{ $alert_type }} </span>
```

This could help you.

If you want to know more on how to pass value to view, here is the link to docs:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to display the json response value in blade.